# Assign group numbers across all combinations in two columns

Tags: grouping, multiple-matches

I have used pairwise cosine similarity to compare a bunch of company names and I have all the pairwise matches. I need to assign group numbers that take into account all the combinations, rather than just the first column. Some examples I found that used group_by() gave group numbers based solely on item1, not extending to the rows identified in item2.

Sample data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bB4G.png)

Desired output is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSZ0D.png)

The output could also just be a column added to the sample data but with unique group numbers across all matched rows.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question.

Comment: What language + framework(s) are you working in?  Please [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) your question with the technologies you are using.  Also, any chance you could [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing the code you have you written so far, and where are you stuck?  From [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem...  if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some...Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*

Comment: Here is the sample r code that assigns id numbers to unique values in item1 but not across item2

Names2 <- Names[Names$similarity > 0.8,]
by_items <- Names2 %>% group_by(item1, item2)
by_items %>% mutate(id = cur_group_id())
by_items